# Abecedario intercalado de minúsculas y mayúsculas

Tags: php

Estoy realizando un acortador solamente con 5 letras, que intercale minúsculas y mayúsculas. Lo que tengo hecho hasta ahora no intercala simplemente pone la letra siguiente dependiendo de si está capitalizada o no. Quisiera automatizar el proceso.

Este es mi código `PHP`:

```php
function siguienteLetra($letra)
{
    for($x = $letra; $x < 'zzzzz' || $x < 'ZZZZZ'; $x++)
    {
        $x++;
        $siguiente = $x;
        break;
    }
    return $siguiente;
}
```

Y esto es lo que reproduce siempre siendo dependiente de la letra anterior.

```php
siguienteLetra("aaaaz"); // aaaba
siguienteLetra("aaaaZ"); // aaabA
siguienteLetra("aaaAz"); // aaaBa
siguienteLetra("aaaAZ"); // aaaBA
```

Cualquier solución, aporte o consejo será de mucha ayuda.

Desde ya,muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta es la solución, otro bucle `for` que se fije si alcanzó la "z" minúscula o mayúscula.

Código **`PHP`**:

```php
function nextLetter($letter)
{
    for($x = $letter; $x < 'zzzzz' || $x < 'ZZZZZ'; $x++)
    {
        $x++;
        $next = $x;
        break;
    }
    return $next;
}

function toUpLowCase($letter)
{
    for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
    {
        if($letter[$i] == "z")
        {
            $letter[$i] = "A";
        }
        elseif($letter[$i] == "Z")
        {
            $letter = nextLetter($letter);
            $letter[$i] = "a";

        }
    }
    echo $letter;
}
```

```php
$letter = "aaaZz";
echo toUpLowCase($letter); // "aabaA"
```

Answer (score 4):

Puedes convertir el string en un array.

## Versión simple

Creas una funcion donde:

- Transformas el string en un array.
- Lo recorres letra por letra.
- Pones un condicionante donde $n si es par convierte en mayúscula y par en minúsculas.
- En cada resultado del `if` concatenas la letra en un nuevo string llamado `$resultado`.
- Devuelves la cadena resultante `$resultado`.

  ```
  function intercalado($string) {

    $n = 0;
    $resultado = '';
    $string_en_array = str_split($string);

    foreach ($string_en_array as $letra) {

      if($n%2 == 0) {
        $resultado .= strtoupper($letra);
      } else {
        $resultado .= strtolower($letra);
      }
      $n++;
    }
    return $resultado;
  }

    echo intercalado('hola como estas');

   ?>
  ```

Resultado:

> ```
> HoLa cOmO EsTaS
> ```

---

## Versión con abecedario y límite de caracteres

Función con 2 parametros:

- El primero es la cadena si es `null`, genera un abecedario.
- El segundo determina la cantidad de caracteres. Si se deja a `0`. No hace ningún corte. De lo contrario eliminara x caracteres empezando por el final.

  ```
  function intercalado($string, $n_letras = 0) {

    $n = 0;
    $resultado = '';

        if($string === null) {
            $letra = "A";
            for ($i =0; $i < 30; $i++){
                    $string .= $letra++;
                }
        }

      if($n_letras > 0 ) {
        $string = substr($string, 0, -$n_letras);
      }

    $string_en_array = str_split($string);

    foreach ($string_en_array as $letra) {

      if($n%2 == 0) {
        $resultado .= strtoupper($letra);
      } else {
        $resultado .= strtolower($letra);
      }

      $n++;
    }
    return $resultado;
  }
  ?>
  ```

**Cómo usarlo:**

```
<?php
    echo intercalado('hola', 0);
    echo "<br />";
    echo intercalado(null, 20);
    ?>
```

Resultado:

> HoLa
>   AbCdEfGhIjKlMn